# A question about power amplification concept of a BJT

Tags: current, bjt

In a text I'm confused about a part concerning BJT transistor operation:

[image]

Below is the paragraph regarding the above transistor models:

[image]

The text explains the transistor operation for the PNP transistor.

What does the text mean here? It says "the output circuit carries the same current". Here Im really confused. Isnt the the output circuit current is *beta* times the base current? The text says "the same current".. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This is a "common base" configuration. Read [all about it at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Common Base Amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93035/common-base-amplifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking a very specific question about your own personal state of mind when faced with this text and I'll give a shot at addressing what I suspect is your misconception without hauling in a lot of abstract stuff:

The text is right when it says that the input current and the output current is the same. (Technically, it is not exactly the same. But it is the same "for all intents and purposes.") This is despite your recollection that the "output circuit current is beta times the base current." Your recollection is for a common-emitter arrangement. This is a common-base, though.

It might be easier for you to see this if I do a little diagram. Please don't worry about all the complexity present here. It's mostly just to get things arranged somewhat more realistically. It's simpler than it looks:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0BVcf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, you have a common-base BJT arrangement. Think of the base as being "nailed to a voltage." Almost like you'd nail something to a wall (imagine the floor as ground and the ceiling as \$V_{CC}\$.) It's just suspended there.

The emitter "hangs off" from that nailed down base voltage, about one \$V_{BE}\$ less. The resistor \$R_E\$ is just there to set the DC operating current for \$Q_1\$, which will be about \$I_{E_Q}=\frac{V_B-V_{BE}}{R_E}\$. Also, \$I_{C_Q}=\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}I_{E_Q}\approx I_{E_Q}\$.

Now I want to call your attention to this last paragraph! Note that there is \$\beta\$ in the equation, just as you imagined when you wrote. Yes, \$\beta\$ is involved. But also note that because of the way things are arranged, it drops out, too. This is because the base can be ignored in this circuit, as the "important stuff" isn't going on at the base. It's going on at the emitter and the collector. And the emitter current and the collector current are almost equal to each other. This is why you read a statement telling you that the input current and the output current is the same (well, almost the same.)

Now let's look at the power situation. Suppose a tiny signal wiggles one side of transformer \$L_1\$. This will stimulate a wiggle on the other side, which acts like an AC signal source. The AC signal source here "sees" through the capacitor \$C_E\$ (which we assume looks like a dead-short at the frequency of interest) and causes a slight fluctuation at the emitter of \$Q_1\$. This tiny fluctuation modifies the standing (DC) emitter current slightly. The impedance seen by this signal source will be \$r_e=\frac{V_T}{I_{E_Q}}\$, due to the way that the BJT functions. (I'd have to take the derivative of its equation to show you why.) Here, \$V_T\approx 26\:\textrm{mV}\$ at room temperature and is called the thermal voltage. (It's a physical thing that is true for any matter and is based on the equi-partition rule of energy.) \$I_{E_Q}\$ is, of course, set by \$R_E\$. The output impedance will be \$R_L\$ (as seen through \$L_2\$.)

Let's do the equation thing now. I'll use small letters to signify the tiny AC signals and big letters to signify the DC values of things:

$$\begin{align*}
r_{in} &= r_e & \textrm{ } p_{in} &= \frac{v_{in}^2}{r_e}\\\\
i_e &= \frac{v_{in}}{r_e} & \textrm{ } i_c &= \frac{\beta}{\beta+1}i_e\approx i_e\\\\
p_{out} &= i_c^2\: R_L = \left(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\frac{v_{in}}{r_e}\right)^2\: R_L\\\\
&\therefore\\\\
\frac{p_{out}}{p_{in}} &= \frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\frac{v_{in}}{r_e}\right)^2\: R_L}{\frac{v_{in}^2}{r_e}} =\left(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\right)^2\: \frac{R_L}{r_e}\approx \frac{R_L}{r_e}
\end{align*}$$

As it turns out, this can be quite a large power gain! In fact, the common base arrangement can have probably the highest possible power gain for any single BJT arrangement.

Yet note that the emitter current (input side) is about the same as the collector current (output side.) And note that I did use \$\beta\$ here, too. It's just that it mostly "goes away" for purposes of figuring out what is happening with regard to the outputs and inputs of this arrangement.

Comment: What I understand and confused from text that the text says the base current is equal to the collector current i.e Ib = Ic. What you show is Ic = Ie???  What is meant by "input current" in the text? Isnt it the base current Ib??

Comment: @user134429 No! The input current is **not** the base current! That is your misconception.

Comment: I reread your answer and I understand your derivations. Just Im stuck at a point about thermal voltage Vt. Is Vt related to the change in potential difference of Vbe?? I think we can write rin=re=ΔVbe/ΔIe ?? So can we say that thermal voltage Vt=(ΔVbe/ΔIe)xIe ??

Comment: @user134429 No. \$V_T\$ is about physics. It's based on the equi-partition law of energy distributed through all of the available degrees of freedom in constrained matter (solids, liquids, and contained gases.) It's based on large number population statistics and since even a tiny bit of a matter has quadrillions of modes, it's uniformly true about pretty much any matter you will ever see. At room temp, \$V_T\approx 26\:\textrm{mV}\$.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show you a much more practical example for a Common Base amplifier.

Also in this example I teat BJT as a Current Controlled Current Source. 
I also ignore the base current influence on the circuit. 
And finally, I assume \$I_E = I_C \$.

We usually can do suach approximation if the \$ \beta> 100\$ because for \$ \beta> 100\$ we have a small error \$I_C = \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1 }I_E \approx 0.99I_E \$ not a big error.

[image]

Try to analysis this example circuit very carefully.

Note that \$V_{in}\$ source contains a DC component (**0.6V**) and the AC component. Hence the AC component is "present" across \$R_E\$ resistor (emitter follower).

And the input current is equal to the output current \$I_E = I_C\$.

No current gain. But we have the voltage gain \$ A_V = \frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{ \Delta V_{IN}}=\frac{10V - 5V}{2.1 - 1.6} = 10 V/V \$.

And this voltage gain is set by the resistance ratio \$\frac{R_C}{R_E}\$

Comment: What I understand and confused from text that the text says the base current is equal to the collector current i.e Ib = Ic. What you show is Ic = Ie???  What is meant by "input current" in the text? Isnt it the base current Ib??

Comment: @user134429 No, the book did not talk about the base current as a input current. Notice that the \$V_i\$  input source is connected in series with Vbb battery between GND and the Emitter terminal.  Hence the \$V_i\$  source must provide the emitter current Apply the KCL for this loop and you will see that the emitter current is the input current. You have exactly the same situation in my diagram. Vin current = Emitter current and the Emitter current = base current + collector current.

Answer (score 0):

In common base the current gain and bias determines the emitter input impedance ( few hundred ohms) but in this configuration, Rin is low while output is a current source. Essential with a grounded base the emitter voltage is negative but using (positive) Vbe curve you can see it starts to become linear > 0.65V in the 10~100mA range, depending on V+.  Keep Vce>=2V for best linearity to avoid saturation.

Keep in mind Gnd is just a 0V 0 Ohm reference. It can be floating from earth and you can even bias it to 1V so your emitter input is above 0V.  But there is an offset voltage, to consider always.

Thus with voltage gain being Rc/Re you can choose Vbe from the datasheets and choose Re  to be >>Rbe= few hundred Ohms) for improved linearity i.e. >=1k

I am using the VCCS model here.

[image]